# How to override the opacity of document.body?

Tags: javascript, html, css, document-body

I want to make the body of my website have a low opacity but keep a popup at the default opacity of 1 so that it stands out.

How can I do this? I've tried specifying that the popup has `opacity: 1 !important;` but it doesn't take effect.

Here is a jsfiddle with my attempt: **https://jsfiddle.net/80351/0xo10tjc/**

Please note that I know how to achieve this by setting the opacity of an outer div instead of body at 0.2 but I really want to know if this is possible to do when changing body.

Comment: use `rgba(255,255,0,0.2)`

Comment: Are you expecting the desktop to be shown behind the browser window?? What benefit is there to applying opacity on the body tag itself? There's nothing behind the body tag. If you want a faded color.. then use the value for the faded color, not opacity.

Comment: Never a good idea to style the body - you should use a wrapper on your site and style that instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set html and body to have 100% height and apply `background-color` to a div

```
html, 
body {
   height: 100%;
}

body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.overlay {
  background-color: yellow;
  opacity: 0.2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0xo10tjc/4/